# Not able deselect design mode in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with many `scroll-bars` and `check-boxes`. It works fine in my laptop.
When I use this file in another computer, I am not able to control the `objects`, it is always in `design mode`. I am not able to release from `design mode`. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Click on

1. File Tab | Excel Options | Trust Centre | Trust Centre Setting | ActiveX Settings
2. Select `Prompt me before enabling all controls with minimal restrictions`

[image]

**EDIT:**

Also check these two things

1. Macro Settings (Below ActiveX Settings)
2. Does your MS Office supports Macros. Which Version does this happen on?

Comment: Thanks for your ans.Now my axtiveX setting is "Enable all controls without restrictions and without prompting".My version is office 2007.

Comment: What abput macro settings? Also do you get a YELLOW Security bar when you open Excel?

Comment: Macro setting is enable all. Yellow security bar does not appear